# Python Base64 decode failed error in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64

I have the error as `"Base64 decode failed"` using the following function. The following function is used to call the model that is saved in Google AI Platform. However, the data input has to be base64 serialized, hence, I include the get_serialized_example(raw) function within the tfx_test(request). Any help and advice are appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
def tfx_test(request):
    
    #User Inputs
    project = request.project
    model = request.model
    signature = request.signature
    version = request.version
    
    #Data inputs Base64 encoder 
    
    def get_serialized_example(raw):
        return tf.train.Example(
                features=tf.train.Features(
                  feature={"value":
                              tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[raw]))
                          }
                    )
                ).SerializeToString()


    b64_country_code = base64.b64encode(get_serialized_example(request.country_code)).decode('utf-8')
    
    b64_project_type = base64.b64encode(get_serialized_example(request.project_type)).decode('utf-8')
    
    # ml.googleapis.com
    service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('ml', 'v1')
    name = 'projects/{}/models/{}'.format(project, model)

    if version is not None:
        name += '/versions/{}'.format(version)

    response = service.projects().predict(
        name=name,
        body={
            'signature_name': signature,
            'instances': [
                    {
                       "examples":{"b64": b64_country_code[0],
                                   "b64": b64_project_type[0]}
                    }]
        }
    ).execute()

    if 'error' in response:
        raise RuntimeError(response['error'])

    return response['predictions']
```

Comment: Are you getting the error in your code, or does it come back from Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're not senfing a valid base64 string. Instead, you're just sending the first character:

```
"examples":{"b64": b64_country_code[0],
            "b64": b64_project_type[0]}
```

The first character of a base-64 string is *not* a valid base 64 string, as base64 encoding takes every three characters and encodes them as four.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. if I take out the [0], I have the following error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

Comment: Do you get this error from Google, or from the client side code?

Comment: From client side.

Comment: And the data input is as follow: class request(): country_code = b"AU"
    project_type = b"Delivery". I ran a unit test on the function, and that's what I got as the error too.

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to provide more information - perhaps in a new question with all the details.

Comment: Thanks Roy2012, here is the link to the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62549037/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-str-on-unit-testing

Comment: If I (at least) helped you with the base64 error, it would be great if you could accept my answer for future generations :)