# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str on Unit Testing

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64

I have the error as `"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str "` while running a unit test on the following function. The following function is used to call the model that is saved in Google AI Platform. However, the data input has to be base64 serialized, hence, I include the get_serialized_example(raw) function within the tfx_test(request). Any help and advice are appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
def tfx_test(request):
    
    #User Inputs
    project = request.project
    model = request.model
    signature = request.signature
    version = request.version
    
    #Data inputs Base64 encoder 
    
    def get_serialized_example(raw):
        return tf.train.Example(
                features=tf.train.Features(
                  feature={"value":
                              tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[raw]))
                          }
                    )
                ).SerializeToString()


    b64_country_code = base64.b64encode(get_serialized_example(request.country_code)).decode('utf-8')
    
    b64_project_type = base64.b64encode(get_serialized_example(request.project_type)).decode('utf-8')
    
    # ml.googleapis.com
    service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('ml', 'v1')
    name = 'projects/{}/models/{}'.format(project, model)

    if version is not None:
        name += '/versions/{}'.format(version)

    response = service.projects().predict(
        name=name,
        body={
            'signature_name': signature,
            'instances': [
                    {
                       "examples":{"b64": b64_country_code,
                                   "b64": b64_project_type}
                    }]
        }
    ).execute()

    if 'error' in response:
        raise RuntimeError(response['error'])

    return response['predictions']
```

**UNIT TESTING**

def test_safety_kfp_custom(self):

```
self.request = TestScenario.populated_request(Test.test1)
self.response = tfx_test(self.request)

self.assertEqual(0.35915321111679077, self.response["predictions"])
```

**Data Input for tfx_test function**

```
class request():
    project = "xxx"
    model = "xxx"
    signature = "xxx"
    country_code = b"UK"
    project_type = b"PT"
    version = 'xxx'
```

Comment: Could you please include the entire stack trace of the exception?

Comment: I think you probably meant to return response instead of response['predictions'] from tfx_test?

Comment: Thank you Roy2012 and Zenith. Zenith you are right, I should take out the ['predictions'] on the return response. I have a follow-up question. The prediction output is a dictionary, [{'outputs': [0.8]}], how do I put in my unit testing so it passes? Thanks again

Comment: Thank you all. I have figured it out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As Zenith mentioned in the comment, I should return the response instead of response['predictions'] on the return of the function. Thanks,